# Possible SQL injection. How to locate and fix?

Tags: mysql, sql

Google Search Console is saying that certain suspicious URLs in my site are returning a 403 error. They look exactly like this (the links below are not my sites, just examples):

https://www.languagetesting.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=free%20url%20indexer%2C%E3%80%90Visit%20Sig8%2Ecom%E3%80%91backlinksindexer%20review%2CLinks%20Indexer%2Cindexer%20url%2Curl%20index%20checker%2CCheapest%20price%20and%20fast%20index%2Cbacklink%20indexer%20online%20free%2Cgoogle%20url%20index%20tool%2Cbacklinks%20indexer%20review%2CUrl%20Indexer%2Cfast%20backlink%20indexing%2C....3605

and

https://www.flykolibri.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=coins%20fc%2024%20xbox%2C%E3%80%90Visit%20Coinsnight%2Ecom%E3%80%91fc%2024%20coins%20g2a%2Cfc%2024%20promotion%20coins%2Cfc%20coins%20pc%2Cfc%20coins%2024%20buy%2Cfc%20coins%20safe%20to%20buy%2C....72a7

A quick Google search for "sig8" and "coinsnight" reveals that many sites are affected by this. I am guessing it's some kind of SQL injection.

How do I go about finding and removing this in my Wordpress instance? I did a `mysqldump` of the database and searched for those domains (sig8, coinsnight, they are the same in my blocked URLs), just to try to locate the post or entry, but it doesn't find anything.

On my site, all pages affected are search pages. They look like this:

domain.com/?s=coins%20fc%2024%20xbox%2C%E3%80%90Visit%20Coinsnight%2Ecom%E3%80%91fc%2024%20coins%20g2a%2Cfc%2024%20promotion%20coins%2Cfc%20coins%20pc%2Cfc%20coins%2024%20buy%2Cfc%20coins%20safe%20to%20buy%2C....72a7

Comment: I don't see the SQL injection myself, but just because someone's attempting an injection attack on your site doesn't mean you're vulnerable. If these are getting 403s does that mean you have a security plugin that's rejecting these?

Comment: If Google Search Console is alerting to the URLs though, it means they must exist and it's trying to crawl them. So even if Googlebot is blocked by the WAF, the SQL injection must have succeeded at some point, which resulted in their creation.

Comment: See [this](https://www.malcare.com/blog/spam-link-injection-wordpress/) or [this](https://secure.wphackedhelp.com/blog/spam-link-injection-wordpress/amp/) or just search for "spam link injection" on Google..

Comment: Thanks for the links - they are right on the money, though they mostly try to sell plugins. I'd like to manually investigate and remove the problem. I'd like to know how I can locate the SQL injection in the database.

Comment: You could just ignore their sales pitches and focus on their good suggestions, e.g. both the links I shared, they stated, "Clean your database" and to look for functions like `eval`, `gzinflate`, `shell_exec`, and `base64_decode`. And did you do that Google search? Were all the results just trying to sell plugins?

Comment: I spent several hours looking at webpages dealing with this issue, the vast majority lists plugins and offer information that is too general, ie no concrete steps. I did come across what you describe, I did a mysqldump of the db and scanned it for the keywords you mention and others, none found. I suspect the data is serialized, I just need a little help locating it and unserializing it.

Comment: Even if it was serialized (the standard PHP way), if the db dump contained any of that keywords, you would have seen it already, unless maybe, if they are not spelled "correctly", e.g. it could be `'ev'.'al'` or something like that. And actually, have you scanned your plugin and theme files, as well as WordPress core files, for those keywords? Or malicious PHP/JS code? BTW, please tag me when you reply, so that I will be notified of your replies.

Comment: @SallyCJ after further research, it looks like it's a form of search box spam, maybe not SQL injection as I feared. I can't find much on dealing with this. Let me know if you have any thoughts on how to remove it. I flushed page cache but it's still there. And yes I scanned all files for those keywords, no matches.

Comment: Google has a [tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9689846?hl=en) for [removing those spam URLs](https://www.contentkingapp.com/academy/google-remove-urls/#spam), so you can try it out. But the removal doesn't seem permanent, so returning a 404 or 410 status for those seach results might be a more reliable approach, in addition to filtering the search keyword to check if it's spammy, e.g. using Akismet, and perhaps you can [try this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cleantalk-spam-protect/).

Comment: Just a quick update, there is no SQL injection. I am using the W3TC cache plugin and I have it set to cache URLs with query strings. What these spammers are doing is exploiting that to post search queries with their spam strings, which get cached. I need to exclude search queries from getting cached, but the exclusion rules are not working right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not a SQL injection, but spam links in cache indeed. What happened was, the cache plugin was set not to cache search pages, but due to some glitch it was caching them anyway. The problem with the plugin was fixed at some point and the problem disappeared. Thank you guys.